# localStorage not storing data in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have this line of code insade a vue method.

```
browser.localStorage.setItem("blocked_urls", JSON.stringify(this.urls));
```

I want to save a list of urls that the user will prompt inside a textarea in option page to use them later in my background script to pass them to the `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` method.
I have declared the storage permission in manifest and the webRequest and webRequestBlocking permissions without problem, what is happening is that I'm not able to store the data and retrive them.

In the background script I have this code, and will give me an error because the local storage key and data are not set. How I can fix this and pass the result to a formatted array that can work with webRequest method correctly?

background.js

```
// this will not work to get the data
const settings = browser.localStorage.getItem("blocked_urls");

// I need to pass the retrived settings to the array in the expected format ex: ["https://www.myurl.com/","https://www.myurl1.com/"] ecc.
const sitesList = [];

console.log(settings);

browser.webRequest.onBeforeSend.addListener( (details) => {
  console.log(details);
  return { cancel: true }
},{
  urls: sitesList
},["blocking"]);
```

Comment: Have you tried `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "browser.localStorage.getItem('blocked_urls')"'});` ?

Comment: no because I have a dedicated option page in a vue single file component and I'm running all the logics to get data and block urls from the background script that is persistent

Comment: There's no such thing as `browser.localStorage`. There is `window.localStorage` (same as `localStorage`) and `browser.storage` which is an entirely different API.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, so I've made a mistake about this.I was using browser to make things working also on opera and firefox. I need to fix the syntax. For the array, do you have a suggestion to format it?

Comment: I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined` error if I try use `browser.storage.local.set()` and `browser.storage.local.get()`

Comment: browser.storage needs a permission in manifest.json, see examples. Also, it's asynchronous so you may want to move the registration of webRequest event into then().

Comment: I already set the `unlimitedStorage` permission in my manifest.json

Comment: It needs an API permission, see examples.